# Issue tokens concurrently with synchronization per client

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, http, client

I have an API application with token authorization. A token is valid for one hour. Each business client has its own instance of the API application:

> ```
> {"client_1": "http://localhost:1"},
> ...
> {"client_n": "http://localhost:n"}
> ```

In another application I have a class `ApiService` to make HTTP requests to the API. I create one instance of `ApiService`. Requests happen concurrently and I want to be sure that for each client token will be issued only once. I use [Flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl) to make HTTP requests.

```
public class TokenDetails
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDetails
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class ClientService
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<TokenDetails>> _tokens =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<TokenDetails>>();

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _locks =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(ClientDetails client)
    {
        var token = await GetTokenAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return await new Url(client.BaseAddress).AppendPathSegment("/data")
            .WithOAuthBearerToken(token.Token)
            .GetStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private Task<TokenDetails> GetTokenAsync(ClientDetails client)
    {
        //try find valid token task
        if (!_tokens.TryGetValue(client.ClientId, out var tokenTask) 
            || tokenTask.IsFaulted 
            || tokenTask.IsCanceled 
            || (tokenTask.IsCompleted && tokenTask.Result.Expires < DateTime.UtcNow))
        {
            //token task not found or token is expired - enter lock to make http call
            var lockObject = _locks.GetOrAdd(client.ClientId, id => new object());
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                //try find valid token task again after aquiring lock
                if (!_tokens.TryGetValue(client.ClientId, out tokenTask) 
                    || tokenTask.IsFaulted 
                    || tokenTask.IsCanceled 
                    || (tokenTask.IsCompleted && tokenTask.Result.Expires < DateTime.UtcNow))
                {
                    //http call
                    tokenTask = new Url(client.BaseAddress).AppendPathSegment("/login")
                        .WithBasicAuth(client.Username, client.Password)
                        .GetJsonAsync<TokenDetails>();
                    _tokens.AddOrUpdate(client.ClientId, key => tokenTask, (key, oldToken) => tokenTask);
                }

            }
        }

        return tokenTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern looks correct. One disadvantage here is you're blocking threads waiting for the lock. You could instead use a `SemaphoreSlim` and its [`WaitAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805.aspx) method for a nonblocking lock.

Even better, have a look at [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache). (Scott Hanselman [blogged](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingLazyCacheForCleanAndSimpleNETCoreInmemoryCaching.aspx) about this recently.) It basically does all of this for you - caching, asynchronous double-check locking, and guaranteeing refresh only happens once. You could replace most of what you've done here with a `GetTokenAsync` implementation that looks something like this:

```
return await _tokenCache.GetOrAddAsync(
    $"tokens-{client.ClientId}",
    () => client.BaseAddress
        .AppendPathSegment("/login")
        .WithBasicAuth(client.Username, client.Password)
        .GetJsonAsync<TokenDetails>(),
    TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

One little caveat here is you need to know ahead of time how long to cache the token, i.e. you can't use the `Expires` value returned from the server. But in your case it sounds like you know it's an hour, so hopefully that's a non-issue.